# Swift & ArcGIS - Hard code point location: AGSPoint wont work, despite AGSEnvelope working correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, maps, arcgis

I'm currently trying to work with ArcGIS Maps in Xcode and am having issues with hard coding a location. My code is currently as follows:

```
func mapViewDidLoad(mapView: AGSMapView!) {

    self.graphicLayer = AGSGraphicsLayer()

    self.mapView.addMapLayer(self.graphicLayer, withName: "Graphics Layer")

    let markerSymbol = AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol()
    markerSymbol.color = UIColor.blueColor()

    let markerPoint = AGSPoint(x: 10, y: 49, spatialReference: AGSSpatialReference(WKID: 4326))

    let Graphic = AGSGraphic(geometry: markerPoint, symbol: markerSymbol, attributes: nil)

    self.graphicLayer.addGraphic(Graphic)

    let envelope = AGSEnvelope(xmin: 8.148, ymin:48.188, xmax:11.114, ymax:50.375, spatialReference:AGSSpatialReference(WKID: 4326))

    self.mapView.zoomToEnvelope(envelope, animated:true)

}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the envelope is working correctly, however the marker symbol is centered in the middle of the world map and I'm unable to position it. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple but any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's a projection problem, the map is probably in web mercator, therefore your AGSPoint is nearly the origin of the spatial reference (south of Guinea).

Try setting your AGSGraphicsLayer spatial reference.

If that doesn't work, check what's your map spatial reference and using [GeometryEngine's project](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_geometry_engine.html) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem and solved it by converting marker point from **Geographic** (Lat/Long) coordinates to **Webmarcator** (X/Y) coordinates using **AGSGeometryGeographicToWebMercator(AGSGeometry)** function.

So I think replacing the following line:

```
let Graphic = AGSGraphic(geometry: markerPoint, symbol: markerSymbol, attributes: nil)
```

with

```
let Graphic = AGSGraphic(geometry: AGSGeometryGeographicToWebMercator(markerPoint), symbol: markerSymbol, attributes: nil)
```

will solve the problem.